# Making a replacement 5V reference g sensor

Tags: resistors, potentiometer, accelerometer

I'm looking to make a replacement G sensor for a vehicle for which the sensor is no longer available. Here is some background on the system.

The Gravity (G) sensor is a vertical low-g (gravity) acceleration sensor. By sensing vertical acceleration caused by bumps or potholes in the road, the powertrain control module (PCM) can determine if the changes in crankshaft speed are due to engine misfire or are driveline induced. If the G sensor detects a rough road condition the PCM misfire detection diagnostic will be deactivated.

The G sensor at rest output should be between 2.35V - 2.65V (+1g). During a rough road condition the voltage output can vary between 0.5V (-1g) and 4.5V (+3g).

What could I use to replicate this? I've attached a wiring diagram as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A MEMS accelerometer, should be under the black box. I am sure that you can buy a spare part, or to deactivate this feature in the ECU. The hard way is to make a new one, but in my opinion this is not economically justified.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/knock-sensor-Automotive/s?k=knock+sensor&rh=n%3A15684181   like these?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 absolutely no.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to find a modern replacement.

Otherwise, the easiest "emulation" consists of two terminal switches w/ levers and weights and a few resistors.

p.s. I would disable such a "feature" in my car in a heartbeat.